# What do Lightning Reeds, Grave Busters, and Coconut Cannons do?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

What powers do lightning reed, grave buster, and coconut cannon have?

Comment: Power for what?  When using Plant food?

Comment: no plant food for this

Comment: A simple google search, or just playing the game, will give you this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the attacks and powers of each of the plants you have mentioned above:

**Lightning Reeds**

> Normal attack:
> Lightning Reeds fire electricity at the closest enemy within 3 lanes
> of where it is planted similar to the Threepeater. The electricity
> will also arc to another enemy if close enough.
>
> Plant Food Upgrade: The Lightning Reeds plant
> food upgrade is that it will generate a small storm cloud that chases
> zombies, dealing massive damage and will then move onto another target
> and do the same.

**Grave buster**

> Normal Use: Grave Busters consume graves they're planted on. Usage:
> single use, must be planted on graves.
>
> Plant Food Upgrade: -None-

**Coconut Cannon**

> Normal attack: Its usage involves tapping on it where it releases a
> cannonball (coconut) in a straight line in front of it where it will
> explode when it hits the first zombie doing splash damage (3x3 area).
> A direct hit from the Coconut Cannon deals approximately 45 normal
> damage shots. It then requires a cooldown period of 16 seconds.
>
> Plant Food Upgrade: The Coconut Cannons plant food upgrade allows it
> to release a gigantic coconut, pushing all zombies to the right of the
> screen doing incredible damage as well as killing each zombie in a 3x3
> area at the end. Can still be used during cooldown, but will start it
> if not.

**Links**

[Lightning reeds](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_Reed)

[Grave buster](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Grave_Buster)

[Coconut cannon](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Coconut_Cannon)

Comment: [Always link to your source](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_Reed) when copying text.